# $\bigcap I_i = \prod I_i\, $ if $\,I_i+I_j=R\,$ for $i\neq j\ $ [lcm = product for coprime ideals]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Consider a rng $R$ and ideals $I_1,\dots , I_n$ such that $I_i+I_j=R$ for $i\neq j$. Show that the inclusion $\prod I_i\subseteq \bigcap I_i$ is an equality (Exercise 1.1.4, Bosch's Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra)

I already  proved  Chinese remainder theorem (in the previous exercise), but I don't know how to approach this one, and I've been thinking for a while. Even if I show $R/\prod (I_i)\cong R/ \bigcap (I_i)$, the thesis is not proven, and I can't think of anything else. Can you only give a hint to start? Thank you

Comment: I would do this by induction. Of course $IJ\subset I\cap J$. Also, there are $a\in I,b\in J$ such that $a+b=1$, so, if $z\in I\cap J$, then $z=z(a+b)=za+zb\in IJ$. Hence, $IJ=I\cap J$. Now, for the step, use the fact that there exist $a_i\in I_i$ and $b_i\in J_{n+1}$ such that $a_i+b_i=1$ for all $i\leq n$.

Comment: @XuguiManuel Why $za + zb \in IJ,$ could you please explain this?

Comment: @MathIgnorance Note that elements of $IJ$ are of the form $\sum^n_{i=1}a_i b_i$, with $a_i\in I$ and $b_i\in J$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sketch of a simple inductive proof. Notice that this an ideal-theoretic generalization of [lcm = product for pair coprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3841440/242).

**Theorem** $\ I_n \cap \cdots I_2\cap I_i\, =\, I_n\cdots I_2 I_1\ $ **if** $\ I_j + I_k = 1\, $ for $j\neq k$.

**Proof** $ $ (Sketch) $\ $ We proceed by (complete) induction on $n$.

Base case: $\,n = 2,\,$ i.e. $\, I\cap J = I J\ $ if $\ \color{#c00}{I+J = 1}.\,$  Direction $\, I\cap J \supseteq IJ$ is clear. Conversely
$\, I\cap J = (\color{#c00}{I+J})(I\cap J) = I(I\cap J) + J(I\cap J) \subseteq IJ.\,$

Induction step: $ $ assume it is true for all $\,k< n.\,$ Then

$$\begin{align}
&I_n \cap (I_{n-1}\cap \cdots\cap I_1)\\
=\ &I_n \cap (I_{n-1}\times \cdots\times I_1)\ \ {\rm by\ induction} \\
=\ &I_n \times (I_{n-1}\times \cdots\times I_1)\ \ \text{by $\,k=2\,$ case & Lemma below }
\end{align}$$

**Lemma** $\ \forall i\!:  \color{#0a0}{I + I_i = 1}\Rightarrow I + I_1\cdots I_{n-1} = 1\,\ $ [[**Euclid's Lemma** in ideal form]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242)

**Proof** $ $ Induct using $\,I + I_i J = I + I_i J + I J = I + (\color{#0a0}{I_i+I})J = I+J$

**Or** $\bmod I\!:\ I_k\equiv 1\Rightarrow \prod I_k \equiv 1^n = 1\ $ [ideal form of [coprimes are closed under product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673192/242)]

Comment: Please take care not to answer duplicated questions.

Comment: @amWhy Of course I searched for a dupe, but did not find one.  Why downvote? Your [proposed dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247315/if-i-1-i-n-distinct-ideals-and-i-ii-j-r-for-any-i-ne-j-then-i-i) is not a good choice - that's my Lemma above, which is only a small part of the proof (one line above).

Answer (score 4):

First assume $n=2$. If $I+J=R$ then we can write $1=x+y$ where $x\in I, y\in J$. So if $z\in I\cap J$ then we have:

$z=z(x+y)=zx+zy\in IJ$

Now try to apply induction in order to prove the general case.

Comment: I do not understand why the line before last implies that $z \in IJ,$ could you please explain?

Comment: @MathIgnorance We have $x\in I$ and $z\in J$, and thus $zx\in IJ$. Similarly, $z\in I, y\in J$ and so $zy\in IJ$. So the sum $zx+zy$ is in $IJ$ as well.